# Treating derived class as base class - how does it help us to prevent writing more code?

Tags: c++

```
class Shape
{
    void draw ();
    void move ();
    void resize ();
}

class Square : public Shape
{
    // Re implement the draw function so that it draws a Square.
    void draw ();
}

void callDraw (Shape& arg) 
{
    arg.draw ();
}

int main ()
{
    callDraw (Square& arg);
}
```

(P.S. I know that we need to use the keyword `virtual` here to make this actually work.)
How does this actually help us in preventing us from writing more code?

In that function too we are calling the draw function like `arg.draw()`. So, how much time will it take for us write that call in the main function?

What point am I missing here?

Comment: Inheritance is not an aid for writing less code. It will often be quite the opposite, that more code is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't result in less code; in this case it lets you keep square logic separate from triangle logic and circle logic; rather than having

```
void draw() {
    if (isSquare) {
      drawSquare();
    } else if (isTriangle) {
      drawTriangle();
    } else if (isCircle) {
      drawCircle();
    }
}
```

You could use a switch-case instead of if-else-ifs but no matter what you do, it's going to be ugly.

With the virtual methods, adding or removing a shape doesn't require going into your Shape.draw() function to modify logic (if you've got several methods it becomes even more relevant); you simply add or remove the shape's class and the rest is taken care of.